# Windows 8 app how to connect to Socket server

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-8

i have done a server using this example [socketAsyncEventArgs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22918/How-To-Use-the-SocketAsyncEventArgs-Class)

in visual studio 2010 and .net 4.0.

Now i'm trying to connect to it from a windows 8 app using StreamSocket but i'm getting a "Acces denied" message.
here is the Client code:

```
private StreamSocket streamSocket;
    public string Server = "192.168.0.101";
    public int Port = 9900;

    public async void Connect()
    {
        streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
        Connect();
        try
        {
            await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(
                new Windows.Networking.HostName(Server),
                Port.ToString()); // getting Acces Denied here

            DataReader reader = new DataReader(streamSocket.InputStream);
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            while (true)
            {
                var bytesAvailable = await reader.LoadAsync(1000);
                var byteArray = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                reader.ReadBytes(byteArray);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

How to fix the problem? Is there another way to send and receive messages using this server?

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Firewall?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably also seeing the following as part of your error message:

```
WinRT information: A network capability is required to access this network resource
```

This is because you need to add a capability to your application that allows you to access local networks.  Double click on the `Package.appxmanifest` file in your project.  Click on the `Capabilities` tab.  Add the `Private Networks (Client & Server)` capability to your project.

Comment: Thanks. I had no knowledge that win 8 app has this stuff :D